# changing values of a dynamically created variable in R

Tags: r

I created some dynamic variables in a function in the following way:

```
someIntegers <- c(4,2,5,7,1,3)
for (i in 1:length(someIntegers))
  assign(paste0("newVector", i), vector("numeric", someIntegers[i]))
```

I want to change the values of these dynamically created vectors:

```
for(i in 1:length(someIntegers)) {
  for(j in 1:someIntegers[i]) {
    # I want to change the values of each of the dynamically created variables here
    assign(paste0("newVector", i, "[", j, "]"), rnorm(1, 0, 1))  # A small edit done here
    # This above line is not giving expected result
  }
}
```

So my question here is, how to change values in dynamically created variables of R? In this case, I want to individually change the values of dynamically created vectors, `newVector1`, `newVector2`, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a better pratice to work with `list` than using `assign`.
We can also combine these two steps using `lapply`, `setNames` and `list2env`

```
someIntegers <- c(4,2,5,7,1,3)
vect_list <- setNames(
    lapply(someIntegers, function(l) rnorm(n = l, mean = 0, sd = 1)),
           paste0("newVector", seq_along(someIntegers))
    )

list2env(vect_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
newVector1
## [1] -0.768529  0.791715 -0.050577 -1.246495

newVector5
## [1] -0.60301
```

If you want to separte these two steps :

1 - create empty vectors of differents length

```
someIntegers <- c(4,2,5,7,1,3)
vect_list <- setNames(
    lapply(someIntegers, function(l) vector(mode = "numeric", length = l)),
           paste0("newVector", seq_along(someIntegers))
    )

str(vect_list)
## List of 6
##  $ newVector1: num [1:4] 0 0 0 0
##  $ newVector2: num [1:2] 0 0
##  $ newVector3: num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
##  $ newVector4: num [1:7] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
##  $ newVector5: num 0
##  $ newVector6: num [1:3] 0 0 0
```

2 - Populate the differents element

```
vect_list <- lapply(vect_list,
                    function(x) "[<-"(seq_along(x), rnorm(length(x))))
str(vect_list)
## List of 6
##  $ newVector1: num [1:4] -0.0775 0.4195 -0.8565 -1.7445
##  $ newVector2: num [1:2] -2.069 -0.209
##  $ newVector3: num [1:5] -1.07 1.26 -1.04 1.97 -2.48
##  $ newVector4: num [1:7] 0.0529 0.3997 -2.2187 -1.3695 0.061 ...
##  $ newVector5: num -0.0461
##  $ newVector6: num [1:3] -0.999 -1.082 -0.789
```

Comment: For 2, why don't you just `lapply(vect_list, function(x) rnorm(length(x)))`?  I'm not entirely sure what your expression does, and I'm guessing it works because `lapply` is just collecting the return values of the assignment to `1`, `2`, etc?

Comment: @BrodieG In this case using `lapply(vect_list, function(x) rnorm(length(x)))` works and is probably more efficient but I wanted to translate what the double loop was doing in the original code which is in line with @Agstudy answer too. Using this approach you replace the old value with new one using an index but with your approach you create a new vector each time.

Comment: Should it then be `function(x) "[<-"(x, seq_along(x), rnorm(length(x))))`?  I'm a bit mystified as to how your original code actually works.  Also, in this case you're not actually replacing into the value in the list, you're just creating a new list (result of `lapply`) that by construction has the same names as the original.  Granted, this is technically exactly what the replace operator does, although in your particular application the replace operator is not actually doing any assignment (`lapply` is, right?).

Comment: Also, +1 for `list2env`

Comment: @BrodieG Yes I think you're right because of `lapply` and it's environment is not a real replacement per se. So your approach is more efficient if we want to populate the whole vector. I think I need to have a better understanding of environment in R. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list containg your variables:

```
vectors <- mget(ls(pattern='newVector'))
```

Then you can easily access to vectors elements like this , for example to access first and second element:

```
vectors[c('newVector1','newVector2')]
$newVector1
[1] 0 0 0 0

$newVector2
[1] 0 0
```

To assign a new value for each element,  you can use `lapply` , for example here I am assign 10 for the first element of each vector of my list:

```
lapply(vectors ,function(x){x[1] <- 10;x})

$newVector1
[1] 10  0  0  0
$newVector2
[1] 10  0
$newVector3
[1] 10  0  0  0  0
$newVector4
[1] 10  0  0  0  0  0  0
$newVector5
[1] 10
$newVector6
[1] 10  0  0
```

Comment: For the last step I think this one is shorter `lapply(vectors, "[<-", 1, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with what others have said about using lists for this type of thing, just for reference, here is one (non-recommended) way to do what you want to do, which is to assign to "dynamic" variables in the top level environment:

```
for(i in 1:length(someIntegers)) {
  for(j in 1:someIntegers[i]) {
    eval(parse(text=paste0("newVector", i, "[", j, "] <- ", runif(1, 0, 1))))
} }
```

And this does what you expect:

```
> newVector1
[1] 0.8895393 0.6928034 0.6405068 0.9942698
> newVector2
[1] 0.6557058 0.7085305
> newVector3
[1] 0.5440660 0.5941420 0.2891597 0.1471136 0.9630242
> newVector4
[1] 0.90229905 0.69070528 0.79546742 0.02461368 0.47779597 0.75845954 0.21640794
> newVector5
[1] 0.318181
> newVector6
[1] 0.2316258 0.1428000 0.4145463
```

I don't know how to do this with `assign` as I don't know how to assign to a subset with `assign`.  Note that a better way to do this would have been to do `assign(paste0("newVector", i), runif(someIntegers[i], 0, 1))` to avoid the `eval` step since for this toy example you can just generate the full length random vector and assign the whole variable, but I provide the other method in case you need to access specific indices.

Note that R provides a cornucopia of functions to operate on list items (`lapply` being one of them), and that as such you should really consider assigning your variables as list elements, and not as top level variables as I show here.

One final note.  If you are going to use `parse`, you need to make sure that you fully control the expression you evaluate (i.e. don't accept input from the web and evaluate it without checking as someone could inject malicious commands).

Comment: Don't forget `fortunes::fortune(106)`

Comment: @dickoa, thanks for introducing me to an essential package. Should be part of base.  What if I manually construct the call by using quote and as.name (jk)?

Comment: Indeed, the `fortunes` package is quite amusing. You already mentionned the danger of `parse` in the last paragraph. I think this note is just a warning or a reminder. Sometimes it's just easier to use `parse`.

Comment: @BrodieG Thanks for letting me know about `parse`, upvote for that. and yeah whoever downvoted, explain yourself when you do so.